# Boundedness of a real-valued sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, absolute-value

I am trying to establish the boundedness of the following real-valued sequence: Given $\alpha \in \left(0,1 \right)$ and $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$, define 
 $$ \left\{  \begin{array}{l}
x_{1} = \alpha \beta , \, x_{2} = 2\alpha^{2} \beta, \\
\displaystyle x_{n+1} = \frac{2n-1}{n} \cdot \alpha \cdot x_{n} - \frac{n-2}{n-1} \cdot x_{n-1} \quad \text{for } n\geq 2.
\end{array}  \right. $$

I tried to plot the first 1000 terms by using Maple with some concrete numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and my guess is that the sequence above is bounded. In addition, I tried to use the triangle inequality to prove the boundedness, but it was stuck.

Now my attempt is to guess the bound and then use induction; however, it seems to be hard in this situation.

Any help would be appreciated. Regards.

Comment: Hint: Try $\beta = 1/\alpha$. Then consider what happens if $\beta$ is different.

Comment: I tried a few cases, but it's still complicated (I think because of the complexity of our recurrent). I think it's a little bit hard to bound this sequence.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect the behaviour of the sequence to depend on the choice of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

As @David remarked, start with $\beta = 1/\alpha$. Let us set $\alpha > \frac 43$. Then $x_1 = 1$ and $x_2 = 2\alpha > 1 = x_1$. Furthermore, we can make the following estimate, using $\frac{2n-1}{n} \geq \frac 32$ and $\frac{n-2}{n-1} \leq 1$, valid for $n\geq 2$.
$$ x_{n+1} \geq \frac 32 \alpha x_n - x_{n-1}\,. $$
Then
$$ x_{n+1} - x_n \geq \left(\frac 32 \alpha - 1\right) x_n - x_{n-1}
\geq x_n - x_{n-1}\,,$$
because $\frac 32 \alpha - 1 \geq 1$ and
by induction it follows that $x_n$ is monotone increasing. We can then estimate
$$ x_{n+1} \geq \frac 32 \alpha x_n - x_n = \left(\frac 32 \alpha - 1\right) x_n \,,$$
which shows that the sequenc $(x_n)$ grows faster than a geometric sequence and hence is unbounded.

I would expect the behaviour to depend on the choice of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. The following is guessing: for large $n$, I would expect the sequence to behave like
$$ x_{n+1} = 2\alpha x_n - x_{n-1}\,,$$
and for this sequence you can find an explicit formula. This could give you intuition for proving boundedness/unboundedness of your sequence.

Comment: How did you get the monotonicity of $\left( x_{n}\right)_{n}$ when $\alpha > 2/3$ and $\beta = 1/\alpha$? I mean, in your second equation, we only have $(3/2)\alpha - 1 > 0$ and it doesn't follows that the right-hand side is positive even when $x_{n} > x_{n-1}$? Hopefully I didn't mess anything up in my mind.

Comment: I just figured out another thing. In your first equation, I think we need to care about the sign of $x_{n}$ so that we can get that estimate.

Comment: I was overly optimistic in my assumptions on $\alpha$. I have changed it to $\alpha > \frac 43$. Now there should be no problems with signs. We start with positive $x_1$, $x_2$ and because of monotonicity, they stay positive.